# How to access http headers in custom authorizer AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

From API Gateway, I created a [custom authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) for my API using Lambda function in python. API Gateway hands over the incoming auth token using a header I configure(`method.request.header.Authorization`). However I also need the other headers of the original http request inside my lambda function. How do I access them? I did not see the headers on `event` object input to my lambda function.

Note that this is not a duplicate of [How to access HTTP headers for request to AWS API Gateway using Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372167/how-to-access-http-headers-for-request-to-aws-api-gateway-using-lambda). The question is about custom authorizer lambda function. I do not see any configuration option to pass the incoming http headers to authorizer lambda function.

As per [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-input), API Gateway calls Custom Authorizer with below input. Base on the the below, I assume my ask is not possible. But want to check if there is a workaround.

```
{
    "type":"TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken":"",
    "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<apiId>/<stage>/<method>/<resourcePath>"
}
```

Comment: not possible. Why do you need more than one header? Workaround: Handle authentication / authorization yourself in the Lambda function of your integration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible by using an Authoriser of type 'Request' instead of Token

Full details are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Fundamentally, all headers are passed in the event object for a Request authorisation

ie headers object on event

```
    "headers": {
        "X-wibble": "111",
        "X-wobble": "222",
        "x-amzn-ssl-client-hello": "*Deleted*",
        "Via": "1.1 .cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "*Deleted*",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "GB",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "User-Agent": "curl/7.55.1",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=*Deleted*",
        "Host": "*Deleted*.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "*Deleted*",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SAM template:

```
ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          MyAuthorizer:
            FunctionPayloadType: REQUEST
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthLambda.Arn
            Identity:
              Headers:
                - X-API-KEY
                - X-API-ID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

1. You can define SAM template (API Gateway) and under headers , you can define multiple headers and you can retrieve them in application.
2. In the request, you can get multiple customheaders

   ```
   "headers": {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
           "type": "string",
           "description": "URI that may access the resource"
         },
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
           "type": "string",
           "description": "Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource"
         },
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
           "type": "string",
           "description": "Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request."
         }
       }
   ```

following [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/) will help