# Access http header data in custom authorizer AWS lambda function in Method Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm facing a little problem with my custom authorizer AWS lambda function. In my Header request I have my Authorization token and I have an other data 'My-Internal-Integer' and I was wondering if it is possible to get 'My-Internal-Integer' value in my custom authorizer AWS lambda function thanks to event or context maybe, I don't know. From this topic : [How to access http headers in custom authorizer AWS lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596366/how-to-access-http-headers-in-custom-authorizer-aws-lambda-function) it seems that it's not possible, but do you know if there is a workaround to get 'My-Internal-Integer' value please ?

Alex

Comment: Do you have API gateway in front of the Lambda?  If not, how are you accessing the Lambda?

Comment: Yes I have API gateway in front of my lambda. I have a GET method with a custom authorizer in my Method Request before the access of the Lambda.

Comment: As Jack notes in his response in the thread you posted, this enhancement request has been noted and is on the roadmap. It has not yet launched.